# Render link-field url and title separately in node template in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, templating, theming

If I print my link field in the node template like: [?php print render($content['field_link']); ?] I will get this field rendered the way it's set in the display settings of the content-type.

But what if I want the url and the title of this field print out separately? I could print out a specific value in the array but that's not the way according to http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way

Is there a simple way of doing this in Drupal 7. Thank you!

Comment: You should use `field_view_field`. take a look at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7

Answer (score 2):

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_link');
print render($field[0]['url']);
?>" target='_blank'>View Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$field_title = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_link', array(
    'label'=>'hidden',
    'type'=>'link_title_plain',
));

$field_url = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_link', array(
    'label'=>'hidden',
    'type'=>'link_plain',
));

print render($field_url);
print render($field_title);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your link points out, you should use:

```
$field = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_name');
```

That will return the renderable array which you can dig into and grab individual pieces.

Full example:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');
$output = render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_name', $field[0]));
echo $output;
```

Comment: Thanks for your respons. This is what I did:  


1. Create a field "field_link" in the content-type  

2. In the node template I print out the $field array  

`code`

<?php  
  $field = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_link');  
  print "<pre>";  
  print_r($field);  
  print "</pre>";
?>  

'code'

But then the full array of the node is printed out ... like:

`code`

Array
(
    [#theme] => field
    [#weight] => 0
    [#title] => link
    [#access] => 1
    [#label_display] => above
    [#view_mode] => _custom_display
    [#language] => und
    [#field_name] => field_link

Comment: Added a full example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again Mike, I just tried your snippet but what work for me eventualy was the following      

  `print render($field[0]['url']);   
  print render($field[0]['title']);`

Comment: The example you provided printed out the rendered link with label again. So I don't use the "field_view_field". Am I missing something here?